# implementing google /open id to log into a wordpress website

Tags: plugins, openid, wordpress

so i have tried various plugins to try this including

- loginza looks nice but does not log me in just redirects me back to
  my homepage and its in russian
- janrain loog very good and theres a simple-modal login plugin that looks brilliant too. but it very expensive as i need this for multiple blogs.
- open id i think this turns you into an open id provider non the less i need a google button for my login

why i need this is my users have a name@mydomainname.com but google hosted and this eliminates our use for lots of password. also looks like a lot of other people are looking for a solution to this. any one got any ideas how i can get this

Answer (score 0):

Janrain plugin is free check this [link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/).
And he give all social in the [demo](http://wordpress.janraindemo.com/?page_id=2) (try to comment).

**EDIT**

Other solution on [code canyon](http://codecanyon.net/searches?term=login%20social&type=files).

Comment: sorry to say it is not free. below is the membership link 
http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/pricing

Comment: yes but try last link i added may be you can find what you want

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, the best plugin for this kind of job is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/
It covers not only Google but other services as well (Facebook, Twitter, WordPress.com)

Here you can find some details on installing it
http://giannopoulos.net/2011/12/28/how-to-add-facebooktwitteretc-authentication-on-wordpress/